# Installation Wizard - Choose or Upload click throws error

Tags: installation

Using Sitecore 8.1

#### Expected Behavior

Start the installation wizard, choose/click on "Upload package" which will bring up the dialog for selecting and uploading a package file. Or if you already have the package in place, the click on "Choose package" and it will bring up the dialogue to choose the correct installation file.

#### Actual Behavior

Start the installation wizard, choose/click on "Upload package or Choose package" and you will see the error in a popup message window: *'The type initializer for **'Sitecore.Install.Serialization.IOUtils'** threw an exception.'*

#### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

Start the installation wizard, choose/click on "Upload package or Choose package" which presents this error in a popup message window: 'The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Install.Serialization.IOUtils' threw an exception.'

I found a blog post but the solution didn't provide the fix for me: http://bhavikmehtablog.blogspot.com/2017/09/sitecoreinstallserializationioutils_1.html
It's possible that there's another dll missing or corrupt, but I haven't found it and am hoping this has already been solved. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a vanilla installation of Sitecore or did you perform an upgrade?

Comment: It's vanilla 8.1.2

Comment: May be check once if application have sufficient right to access the Packages folder?

Comment: Yes, it has rights. It was a dll - see my comment below from 11/27/2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a comment isn't always seen and not always read... Here's the answer to MY issue and it may help you figure out why you're seeing it as well. Thx!

Update from today: Using WinMerge to compare our QA site versus my local site, I found that the file giving me fits was Mvp.Xml.dll. I had a file that was from 2012 and our implementation was using one from 2017. Not sure how that one got our of sync in my workspace, but every time I would Build locally it would get copied to my local/pc website. This is resolved for me. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue recently while upgrading form 7.2 to 9.

We also had `ITHit.WebDAV.Server.dll` placed correctly. Hence we compared assemblies and configuration files with a Vanilla Sitecore 9.0 instance. There were couple of conflicts, once fixed this features was up and running.

Apologies that I can not point you to exact Dlls which are missing or corrupt in my answer. But I would recommend you to compare your Dlls and Configuration files with a working instance on same Sitecore version, especially if you performed an upgrade.

Comment: I used WinDiff to compare the dll's between my local copy of our site and a new instance I just installed. There were a lot of diffs, so I copied the ones that were identified as different to the problematic site's bin folder (it was as I said a local copy of our site). Anyway, it now works just fine.

Comment: ... and the issue is back! A bit frustrating.

Comment: Same process - since I needed to get it working quickly I ended up copying all the dll's in the bin folder. That works but I'll need to figure out which one(s) are truly the offending dll(s).

Comment: Update from today: Using WinMerge to compare our QA site versus my local site, I found that the file giving me fits was Mvp.Xml.dll. I had a file that was from 2012 and our implementation was using one from 2017. Not sure how that one got our of sync in my workspace, but every time I would Build locally it would get copied to my local/pc website. This is resolved for me. Hope it helps someone else.