# Error while install a Sitecore content package using SPE in Sitecore XP 9.3

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

On day to day basis we need to install some content packages from one environment to another. For that we are using SPE module and the below script to install the package zip.
But it usually fails due to the below mentioned error.

```
Install-Package : The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Install.Serialization.IOUtils' threw an
exception.
At line:5 char:3
+         Install-Package -Path C:\Sitecore\build\DEV2_robots_file_cont ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], TypeInitializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeInitializationException,Spe.Commands.Packages.InstallPac
   kageCommand
```

We have already googled around but could not find any solution for the error. This is what we have tried till now:

1. Verified the powershell version and the SPE version. (Both are similar)

```
PS C:\BuildAgent\work\c64f5a4228e7f408\WebDeploy> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.3866
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.3866
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


PS C:\BuildAgent\work\c64f5a4228e7f408\WebDeploy> Import-Module -Name SPE
PS C:\BuildAgent\work\c64f5a4228e7f408\WebDeploy> Get-Module -Name SPE

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     5.1.0      SPE                                 {ConvertFrom-CliXml, ConvertTo-CliXml, Invoke-GenericMethod, Invoke-RemoteScript...}
```

2. Checked and tried replacing Mvp.Xml.dll from local to the environment. It also did not work.

Below is the code which we are using.

```
    Import-Module -Name SPE
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username speremoting -Password spe -ConnectionUri https://<env_url>
Write-Host $session
Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        # This may make the code easier to maintain.
        Install-Package -Path C:\Sitecore\build\ZIPNAME -InstallMode Merge -MergeMode Merge
}
Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

3. Also tested with help of the below link (but did not work):
   https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/14e9ef98f9e8b450c1b39813d13cbc50#file-speremoting-simpleremoteinstall-ps1

> NOTE: When the above error come. These are the steps we do and the script starts working again.
>
> 1. Restart IIS of the environment.
> 2. Go on the Package installation page on CM and click on Upload package. If the dialog box opens the script works.

Please direct me to fix this issue, as we need a solution for this. Or if there is some other script which we can try.

Comment: I dont think this is something related tp Powershell. Can you compare the dlls between your 2 environments? I guess there is some or the other dll missing. Refer to following posts : 
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13452/installation-wizard-choose-or-upload-click-throws-error/15368
https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/sitecore-ioutils-threw-an-exception/